# Unity and Facebook - iOS won't post, android does

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

having a bit of an issue that I haven't been able to find anywhere. I've created a game using Unity and the Facebook SDK for Unity. It works great in the editor, great when pushed to android....But when I try an iOS install, it won't post onto my timeline or anyone else's and invites don't work....But the android version does.

It brings up the dialog like it should, looks like it's about to invite/post, then just goes back to the game.

I'm using Unity 4.3.4, Facebook SDK for Unity 5.0.3 and Xcode 5.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Some additional news. Facebook SDK for Unity has a tutorial attached to it where they have a pre-built project called Friend Smash to show you how the SDK works. I just ran the completed project through Xcode and pushed it to my iPhone and have experienced the EXACT same issue. Invite appears to be sent (even appears on the screen saying "request sent") and it appears to post my score to Facebook, but again nothing appears on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was my stuff up.

Looks like my request wasn't being given a Post ID. In checking my code, I had written "actionlink", instead of "link" in the "onBragClicked" method which fouled up the process....Yet somehow didn't screw up my android build.

Anyway, thanks for viewing.